# javascript - call function when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, unobtrusive-javascript

Can someone show me what I am doing wrong here?

I am trying to execute a function when a button is clicked.

**The HTML:**

```
<button id="btn1">Press me!</button>
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Press me!"/>​
```

**The javascript:**

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1'),
    btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');


function do() {
    alert('Yay!');
}
btn1.onclick = do;
btn2.onclick = do;​
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/pFYUM) I'm not sure why it's not working. It's probobly something way to obvious for me to notice. :)

Comment: In case someone is wondering, my browser is Chrome 17.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the name of your function from `do` to something that is not a reserved keyword.

- http://jsfiddle.net/pFYUM/1/

Answer (score 4):

`do` is a keyword. If you used a debugger you'd know that.

Answer (score 2):

`do` is a keyword. Change variable name and it will work.